# Choosing a wire gauge for a commercial dishwasher

Tags: installation

I am hooking up a 3ph, 208/230v commercial dishwasher.
There is approx. 125' from panel to washer.
Is 4awg my best bet with a 60amp circuit and a disconnect 5' away from washer?

Comment: What's your actual supply voltage at your site, and what is the amp rating of the dishwasher at that voltage?  Also, why don't you want to use aluminum wire? It's perfect for big feeds like this.

Comment: #6 copper will provide 2.08% voltage drop at 50 amps 230v 125'. Why go larger than the 49-50a in the question? (Unless mfg's requires 60 amp breaker).

Comment: @EdBeal op appears to be using the 20% rule. = 60 Amp Breaker.